# Replace abbreviations with their expansions correctly with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace HYD and HYD. with HYDRAULIC

But as you see HYD. does not get converted. What am I doing wrong?

```
console.log("HYD", /\bHYD\b/gi.test("HYD")) // OK!
console.log("HYD,CYLINDER", /\bHYD\b/gi.test("HYD,CYLINDER")) // OK!
console.log("HYD,CYLINDER", /\bHYD\b/gi.test("HYD,CYLINDER")) // <- OK!
console.log("HYD. CYLINDER", /\bHYD\.\b/gi.test("HYD. CYLINDER")) // NOT OK! Did not recognice HYD.
console.log("HYD.,CYLINDER", /\bHYD\.\b/gi.test("HYD.,CYLINDER")) // <- NOT OK! As I need to convert HYD. with HYDRAULIC..

// Example: 
const abbreviation = "HYD.";
const expansion = "HYDRAULIC";

if(/\bHYD\.\b/gi.test("HYD.,CYLINDER")) { // as this does not returns true I cant continue do the replacement 
  "HYD.,CYLINDER".replace(abbreviation, expansion)
}
```

Comment: Are you building the pattern dynamically? You might use [`/\bHYD(?:\.|\b)/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/QwhXkh/1). Or, building it dynamically, `new RegExp("\\b" + val + "\\.?(?!\\w)")`

Comment: `\b` will not return the 0 length match between 2 non-word characters(like between a dot(`.`) and a `space` or between a dot(`.`) and a comma(`,`)

Comment: The abbreviations and expansions are located in an object I will loop through and check if the string has an abbreviation, if yes then I will replace the abbreviation with its expansion.

Comment: So the abbreviation will always be an variable so I will use the Regex constructor to build the regex

Comment: @IsakLaFleur See my updated comment on top.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! It solved it! Please post it as an answer and I will vote for it.

Comment: @IsakLaFleur See my explanations and the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is quite obvious: in between a `.` and `,`, there is no word boundary, and thus, `HYD.,` does not match the `/\bHYD\.\b/` or `/HYD\.?\b/` regexps.

Moreover, since you are building the regex pattern dynamically, you can't play around with alternatives much.

In this case, the easiest and most convenient solution is by using the unambiguous word boundary `(?!\w)`, a lookahead that fails the match if there is a word char (letter, digit or `_`, this may be further customized) immediately to the right of the current position.

Thus, you need to build the pattern like this (considering that all the search values consist of word chars):

```
new RegExp("\\b" + val + "\\.?(?!\\w)")
```

Note that the backslashes need to be double escaped. The `\\.?` pattern will match 1 or 0 dots, and `(?!\\w)` will require a trailing word boundary.

Note that in case the search values can have special chars (non-word chars), you will need to use something like

```
new RegExp("(^|\\W)" + val.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "\\.?(?!\\w)")
```

and replace with `"$1" + expansion.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')`.

Yes, `.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')` is a necessary action if you are replacing with dynamic literal replacement patterns (as the literal `$` must be doubled inside replacement patterns in JS).